# Angular Typeahead save id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I implemented the autocomplete from Typeahead in my AngularJS application. It works fine, but I need to get an `id` related to each position in autocomplete, since the text could be the same in some cases.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
Stock.controller('ProviderAutocompleteController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.providerSelected = undefined;

    var responsePromise = $http.get("/getProvidersList");

    responsePromise.success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
        var providersList = new Array();

        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++)
        {
            var prov = response[i];
            providersList.push(prov.name);
        }

        $scope.providers = providersList;
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="providerSelected" 
       uib-typeahead="provider for provider in providers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
       class="form-control input-md" required="">
```

The service `getProvidersList` will return in the object, also an ID, for each `provider` how can I get the id of the provider choosen in the autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they select an item, you're passing the entire current object to ngModel.

You should see the ID within

```
providerSelected.id // or whatever the ID is within that object
```

Also if you only want the ID you could change your loop (.name being whatever your text is called within your object)

```
uib-typeahead="provider.id as provider.name for provider in providers"
```

Comment: This give me this error: `Error: Expected typeahead specification in form of "_modelValue_ (as _label_)? for _item_ in _collection_" but got "provider.id as provider.name in providers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"`

Comment: it was missing the for, this is working: `provider.id as provider.name for provider in providers`

Comment: Yes! Sorry I'm on an iPad I missed that part. Hope it's all working now!